# How to exclude private headers from showing up in source browser?

Tags: doxygen, header-files

I have set `SOURCE_BROWSER = NO` and `VERBATIM_HEADERS = YES` because I want clients to be able to see the header files. However, I only want to allow them to see certain headers. How is the best way to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

---

***EDIT***: This appears to work, but I would be interested in any other better ways.

```
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = */.svn/* *debug* *impl* *boost*
```

Comment: You could also mark your private headers with the \INTERNAL tag and then change the INTERNAL_DOCS setting in your confg.  The plus side is that you can generate docs for internal groups with INTERNAL_DOCS turned on and it will mark them with a 'for internal use only' message.  The downside is you (and others) need to remember to mark headers with \INTERNAL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `\internal` tag does not work, you can try `\cond ... \endcond` tags for marking a portion of code to be hidden from Doxygen.