# Exclude header files from graphs - doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I have some legacy c++ code we are trying to document. The code includes headers like `"stdafx.h"` which I do not want to show in the graphs. I cannot change the source so I would prefer to find a way to exclude it using the script file. I have already tried setting the following items:

```
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = YES

CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = YES

EXCLUDE                = *afx*

EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = std::* \ *afx*
```

But I still get these files included. Is there a way to have it not put them in the graphs? If it doesn't document it anywhere I won't necessarily be upset.

Comment: You may want to see this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2264872/2988730

Comment: I cannot modify the source code to put the tags into it. That is why I want to be able to set something in the script file.

Comment: are all the files in the same directory? if not you could exclude these

Comment: All the header files are in the same directories as the source code, and there are about 20 directories I would have to exclude, even if the headers were in a separate location.